# center div HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have my codes here and what I want to do is center it but can't figure out how.

```
                <a href="https://twitter.com/aPearLibrary" target="_blank" ><img src="http://apearlibrary.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/twitter.png"></a>
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4X1n6A2GPjcI7_IcDNOQmw" target="_blank"><img src="http://apearlibrary.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/ytube.png"></a>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/aPearLibrary" target="_blank"><img src="http://apearlibrary.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/fbook.png"></a>
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/apearlibrary" target="_blank"><img src="http://apearlibrary.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/linkin.png"></a>
```

Here is what my code is JS fiddle looks like as is...
https://jsfiddle.net/4fc07vL7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to something like this :

```
<div style="text-align:center">
 <a href="https://twitter.com/aPearLibrary" target="_blank" ><img src="http://apearlibrary.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/twitter.png"></a>
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4X1n6A2GPjcI7_IcDNOQmw" target="_blank"><img src="http://apearlibrary.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/ytube.png"></a>
 <a href="https://www.facebook.com/aPearLibrary" target="_blank"><img src="http://apearlibrary.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/fbook.png"></a>
 <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/apearlibrary" target="_blank"><img src="http://apearlibrary.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/linkin.png"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.container{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  -ms-transform:translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform:translateX(-50%);
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  left:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">        
        <a href="https://twitter.com/aPearLibrary" target="_blank" ><img src="http://apearlibrary.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/twitter.png"></a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4X1n6A2GPjcI7_IcDNOQmw" target="_blank"><img  src="http://apearlibrary.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/ytube.png"></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/aPearLibrary" target="_blank"><img src="http://apearlibrary.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/fbook.png"></a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/apearlibrary" target="_blank"><img src="http://apearlibrary.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/linkin.png"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The  align attribute is not supported in HTML5. So, Use CSS instead.

CSS syntax: `<div style="text-align:center">`

So, you can do this.

```
<div id="links" style="text-align:center">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/aPearLibrary" target="_blank"><img src="http://apearlibrary.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/twitter.png"></a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4X1n6A2GPjcI7_IcDNOQmw" target="_blank"><img src="http://apearlibrary.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/ytube.png"></a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/aPearLibrary" target="_blank"><img src="http://apearlibrary.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/fbook.png"></a>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/apearlibrary" target="_blank"><img src="http://apearlibrary.weebly.com/uploads/8/5/2/5/85251306/linkin.png"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: The <div> align attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

Comment: Thanks. For the info Wim